# How to search for all existing mongodbs for single GET request

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Suppose I have multiple mongodbs like mongodb_1, mongodb_2, mongodb_3 with same kind of data like employee details of different organizations.

When user triggers GET request to get employee details from all the above 3 mongodbs whose designation is "TechnicalLead". then first we need to connect to mongodb_1 and search and then disconnect with mongodb_1 and connect to mongodb_2 and search and repeat the same for all dbs.

Can any one suggest how can we achieve above using python EVE Rest api framework.

Best Regards,
Narendra

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but sounds like you should use Mong DB's Sharding (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) or Replica Set.
Sharding has a "router" (called 'mongos') and it will "know" in which part the item you are looking for can be found.
Otherwise, if these approaches do not match your implementation, you might have to implement a fall-back strategy - find from DB 1, if found then return, if null then find from DB 2, if found then return, if null then find from DB 3, if found then return if null then return null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. you are suggesting a basic search approach. But i need that using python eve framework. because in pyhon eve framework once the get request is completed, how to invoke the get request again by changing the mongodb.

Comment: I'm not sure what is "normal approach" but I do suggest trying to use sharding. try to see if there is any field which can be your sharding key to split the data between instances.

BTW, What is the reason the data is split in the first place

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a recommended way to run multiple instances (especially when the servers might be running at the same time) as it will lead to usage of the same config parameters like for example logpath and pidfilepath which in most cases is not what you want.
Secondly for getting the data from multiple mongodb instances you have to create separate get requests for fetching the data. There are two methods of view for the model that can be used:

> query individual databases for data, then assemble the results for viewing on the screen.
>
> Query a central database that the two other databases continously update.